# Saving data of Leaflet Draw using PHP into MySQL

Tags: leaflet, php, mysql

How do I insert Leaflet Draw coordinates in the MySQL database with id longitude-latitude columns?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Drone fika</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/leaflet.css"/> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
    <!-- <script src="src/leaflet.js" ></script> -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/leaflet.draw.css">
        <!--    ***************  Begin Leaflet.Draw-->

    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/Leaflet.draw.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/Leaflet.Draw.Event.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/leaflet.draw.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/">
    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/Toolbar.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/Tooltip.js"></script>

    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/ext/GeometryUtil.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/ext/LatLngUtil.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/ext/LineUtil.Intersect.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/ext/Polygon.Intersect.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/ext/Polyline.Intersect.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/ext/TouchEvents.js"></script>

    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/draw/DrawToolbar.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/draw/handler/Draw.Feature.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/draw/handler/Draw.SimpleShape.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/draw/handler/Draw.Polyline.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/draw/handler/Draw.Circle.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/draw/handler/Draw.Marker.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/draw/handler/Draw.Polygon.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/draw/handler/Draw.Rectangle.js"></script>

    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/edit/EditToolbar.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/edit/handler/EditToolbar.Edit.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/edit/handler/EditToolbar.Delete.js"></script>

    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/Control.Draw.js"></script>

    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/edit/handler/Edit.Poly.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/edit/handler/Edit.SimpleShape.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/edit/handler/Edit.Circle.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/edit/handler/Edit.Rectangle.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/leaflet-draw/edit/handler/Edit.Marker.js"></script>

    <!--    **************  End of Lealet Draw-->
</head>
<style>
    #map {
        height: 500px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div>
        <!--map display  -->
        <div id="map"></div>
        <?php
        $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "dronfikamap");
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT latitude,longitude,timeN FROM maps WHERE latitude is not NULL or longitude is not NULL or timeN is not NULL");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            exit();
        }
        echo "<table>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td align='center' width='200'>" . $row['latitude'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td align='center' width='200'>" . $row['longitude'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td align='center' width='200'>" . $row['timeN'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        // mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>
    </div>
        


    <!-- mappinmjdkljsdljscript -->
    <script>
        var map = L.map('map').setView([-0.390771, 36.968123], 13);

var openStreet= L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var maerker= L.marker([-0.390771, 36.968123]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
    .openPopup();
    <?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost" ,"root", "","dronfikamap");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT latitude,longitude,timeN FROM maps WHERE latitude is not NULL or longitude is not NULL or timeN is not NULL");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ?>
     var marker = L.marker([<?php echo $row['latitude']?>,<?php echo $row['longitude'] ?>]).addTo(map).bindPopup('<?php echo $row['timeN']?>')
    .openPopup(); 
     <?php
}
?> 
var baseMaps = {
    "openStreet": openStreet,
};


var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
     map.addLayer(drawnItems);
     var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
        draw: {
            circle: true,
          },
         edit: {
             featureGroup: drawnItems
         }
     }).addTo(map);
     map.addControl(drawControl);
    map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
        var type = e.layerType;
        var layer = e.layer;

        var shape = layer.toGeoJSON()
        var shape_for_db = JSON.stringify(shape);
        
        drawnItems.addLayer(e.layer);
        console.log(e);
        var latitude=layer.getLatLng().lat;
        var lagitude=layer.getLatLng().lng;
        // <?php
        // $sql = "INSERT INTO c_map 
        // (latitude,longitude) 
        //  VALUES ('latitude','longitude',
        //  '".mysql_real_escape_string($modelJson)."');";
        ?>

    });
    var overlayMaps = {
    "Drawn items": drawnItems,
    "maeker":maerker,
    "device Locations":marker
};
L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
    </script>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This question is not GIS related and should be posted on StackOverflow site.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new php file and readout the passed data:

insert.php

```
<php
$lat = $_GET["lat"];
$lng = $_GET["lng"];

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "dronfikamap");

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO c_map  (latitude, longitude) VALUES (?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $lat, $lng);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();

?>
```

Send the data in the js file to the php file:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
        var type = e.layerType;
        var layer = e.layer;
        var latitude=layer.getLatLng().lat;
        var lagitude=layer.getLatLng().lng;

        fetch('./insert.php?lat='+latitude+'&lng='+lagitude)
});
```

[Prepare Insert](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

You can extend the insert to whatever you want.

This code is not tested but it should work. Try first if the php file is working on a direct call over the browser: `localhost/insert.php?lat=1&lng=1`